# How many test cases using conditional probability to prove that 2 random variables are independent?

Tags: probability, independence

In general, is it enough to test a single case of conditional probability to assert that 2 variables are independent?

**For example**:

Let's say we have a magic coin we flip twice, such that if it lands on $H$, the next flip is $50\% \ H$ and $50\% \ T$. However, if it lands on $T$, the next flip is $60\% \ H$ and $40\% \ T$.

In this case, no matter which conditional probability case I test for: $P(H|T)$, $P(T|H)$, $P(H|H)$, or $P(T|T)$; all of them show dependence when compared to the overall probability of the second event happening by itself.

**This leads me to believe** that if a single case showed that $P(A|B) = P(A)$ for example, that would be enough to prove the general independence of the 2 variables, without having to go through every possible case.

**But is this true**? In general, does a single case of independence between 2 events imply that the variables are independent? In other words, are all joint probabilities going to reflect the overall dependence/independence of the variables?

What about with more variables? More events? **Is there an intuitive way to think about this**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
if and only if $$P(x \in A, Y \in B) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B),$$
for all possible choices of events $A$ and $B$. So if you
can find just one choice of $A$ and $B$ for which the
displayed equation does not hold, then $X$ and $Y$ are associated,
not independent.

But to show independence, you have to exhaust all possibilities,
showing equality for each.
Consider the following joint distribution table for $X$ and $Y:$

```
 x\y    0   1   2   Total  
 ------------------------
  0    .01 .02 .07   .10
  1    .02 .81  0    .83
  2    .07  0   0    .07
 ------------------------
 Total .10 .83 .07  1.00
```

It is true that 
$$.01 = P(X = 0, Y = 0) = P(X = 0)P(Y = 0) = .1(.1) = .01.$$

But other choices do not work.  For example,
$$0 = P(X = 2, Y = 2) \ne P(X = 2)P(Y = 2) = .07(.07) = .0047.$$
So $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: Thank you for the example, this is helpful. Do you also have to exhaust all possibilities even for a 2x2 joint distribution table? I couldn't find a counter-example using different kinds of biased coin flips for 2 flips (such as in my example), where one joint possibility shows independence and another one dependence.

Comment: In a $2 \times 2$ table, the pattern seems to be set as soon as you put a probability into one of the four cells.